# Run drools file on existing solution for debugging

Tags: drools, optaplanner

I'm working on the VRP and trying to debug rules.  I have a solution that I have manually adjusted after the solving phase and I want to see if a rule is firing or see why a specific solution is not obtained.  How would I run the drools file on the solution object after the solving phase?

Answer (score 0):

Use the dependency optaplanner-test which is new since OptaPlanner 7 Beta. See documentation on how to use it.